# USB cameras with Nanopi M4 using motion package

Tags: motion

Sorry this is a question related to Nanopi M4 but I couldn't find anything pertaining to exactly that

I am using 3 low light HD USB cameras (details on the link below) for my application. https://bluerobotics.com/store/sensors-sonars-cameras/cameras/cam-usb-low-light-r1/
The application requires me to have all 3 cameras live streaming simultaneously on 3 different local host ports of a PC. For the controller, I am using a Nanopi M4 (it is connected to my laptop by a 20m long, CAT-6 ethernet cable)
I am using the motion package to work the cameras

These are the problems I faced -

When all 3 cameras are connected to controller and stream is checked, at any given time I am able to see the livestream of only 2 of the streams. On restarting motion, any one of the hosts shows a grey screen while the other two give me the proper stream. I have tested this multiple times and would appreciate if help on how to go about this issue
We also tried connecting the cameras to my laptop directly using threads in my motion package and all the 3 streams were visible to me simultaneously
A few of the times the port number (seen on dev in the form - video0) have changed while the cameras have been plugged in and left as it is. If anyone has come across this problem, please tell me how you went about this
Attached below is a screenshot of the Tcptrack app when all three cameras were connected at 100% stream quality (set in the motion.conf file)

[image]

The first three rows represent each camera and the rates are unequal for all of them which is not expected. Can anyone help me with a possible explanation to this?
Also when that screenshot was taken, the camera streaming to localhost 8083, was showing up as a grey screen on my laptop, so what is the rate signifying?

Also, to make sure there were no problems with the Nanopi M4 USB ports sourcing the current drawn by the cameras, we gave an external 5V power supply to them – We could only see any 2 out of 3 streams

I have also attached a screenshot from my Nanopi M4 Top showing the CPU usage when all three cameras were connected to stream at 100% quality

[image]

As a last resort, if we are only able to work 2 cameras at a time, please advise if anyone has used switching between the three cameras to choose which ones stay on at any given time
Thank you for your time

Comment: Hello and welcome -- It may is a driver problem with the third camera. Try bound that to make sure it's working by [THIS LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303772/163862).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this isn't my area of expertise
But if there was a problem with the driver of the third camera in particular, then no matter what order I plug them in, it should ALWAYS not show me a feed, but it does in my case
All three cameras do "work". I have tested them individually
Whichever one I plug in last however, gives me this issue

Comment: Bound the third camera and play with configuration when you get a gray screen of that streams. I have had a lot of bad experience with `motion` and cameras and some of them occur because of kernel/driver bugs.

Comment: I tried lower resolution and Im getting 3 stream upto 384x288, but this is too small a window for my application to monitor the fine details of the surroundings. Please suggest a way to be able to increase this resolution and get all the 3 streams working. Also, one of the cameras, randomly switches up it's videodevice number from videodevice18 to videodevice19 when the nanopi reboots, or the cameras are mounted into the same ports again. This would be problematic to my end user who will be unable to check for the same every time there is a problem with the stream. Kindly help with a solution.

Comment: I didn't test but you can increase the resolution AND reduced the stream quality. Check these links: https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#picture_quality || https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#stream_quality

Comment: Yes, I know about the parameters, and manipulating them is what I did to test my camera stream performance as I vary resolution. But the problem is that the moment I increase my resolution beyond 384 x 288, one of my streams stop. I want to have a bigger resolution but I'm guessing there's a bandwidth problem with doing that. Can this be done?
Increased resolution while still being at stream_quality 100?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't try it before but it's logical what you said. It should be working on any resolution with high stream quality.